# Python - Function that have a dataframe to store the results from others functions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying a function that, maybe is very simple, that I want to store the results from other functions and on the end print all the results (Like a logger function).

For that I've the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def append_rows(id, result):
    df = pd.DataFrame([])
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(
        {'id': id,
         'result': result}, index=[0]), ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    return df

def calculator_1():
    for i in range(5):
        print(append_rows(i,'Draft' + i+1))

def calculator_1():
    for i in range(2):
        print(append_rows(i,'Draft' + 1))

print(append_rows('', ''))
```

My expected result is:

```
1,Draft2
2,Draft3
3,Draft4
4,Draft5
5,Draft6
1,Draft1
2,Draft1
```

But the actual result is (:

```
"",""
```

My requirement is to have the a unique function to store the results from others functions, instead of have multiple dataframes from each functions and at the end concatenate all of them into one.

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current append_rows function as is you are creating a new dataframe in each iteration. It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but I imagine you could be interested in adding new rows to your dataframe in each iteration?

In that case I would reccommend the following steps:

- create a dataframe outside of a function
- create a list_of_lists outside of the function
- add each newly created list from your loop to the list of lists
- append the list of lists to the dataframe after the loop

if you are simply interested in creating a log of your iterations then I don't see why you would need a dataframe at all, you can simply print the values in a loop.

Comment: Hum... what I need is to store that information along the multiple functions and save it in memory. I was trying to use a dataframe because I know the structure